Discrepancy in Trade Counts Between Backtesting.py trade list and created trades
I used Backtesting.py to test my algorithm. When I run the following code, the output shows that 'ser' records 2530 trades, but the 'trades' contains 55641 trades. What is the reason for this difference? How can I pass the details of each trades to another function when it is created?
def MA_Signal():
    return df.MA_Signal

def MA_12():
    return df.MA_12

def mine(s, t, side):
    print(s, t, side)

from backtesting import Strategy
trades = []

class MyCandlesStrat1(Strategy):  
    def init(self):
        super().init()
        self.MA_Signal = self.I(MA_Signal)
        self.MA_12 = self.I(MA_12)

    def next(self):
        super().next()
        if (self.MA_Signal == 1) and (self.data.Low > self.MA_12):
            sl1 = self.data.Low - (self.data.High / 50)
            tp1 = self.data.High + (self.data.High / 20)
            self.buy(sl=sl1, tp=tp1)
            mine(sl1, tp1, 'Buy')
        elif (self.MA_Signal == 0) and (self.data.High < self.MA_12):
            sl1 = self.data.High + (self.data.High / 50)
            tp1 = self.data.Low - (self.data.High / 20)
            self.sell(sl=sl1, tp=tp1)
            trades.append((sl1, tp1, 'Sell'))
            mine(sl1, tp1, 'Sell')

from backtesting import Backtest
bt = Backtest(df, MyCandlesStrat1, cash=10_000, commission=.003)
stat = bt.run()
ser = pd.Series(stat)
print(ser)

